# linux commands to search a given folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a folder in `~/Downloads` with lots of
files and folders scattered. This consists of various files of different
extensions. I need to  copy only the
`.pdf` files within various directories to `~/pdfs`

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`:

```
find ~/Downloads -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec cp {} ~/pdfs \;
```

Answer (score 1):

if ~/pdfs exists in your system use the following command

```
cd ~/Downloads ; cp -r *.pdf ~/pdfs
```

if ~/pdfs does not exists in your system use the following command

```
cd ~/Downloads ; mkdir ~/pdfs ; cp -r *.pdf ~/pdfs
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to deal with potential file names with spaces, etc., I would recommend this approach:

```
find ~/Downloads/. -type f -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -I_ cp _ ~/pdfs/.
```